# how to create user accounts using html5, javascript, jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there secure way to create secure users accounts within just Html5,JavaScript or jquery without having to using mysql server?i'm trying to setup restriction so only the people who are registered will have access the others will have to option to sign up where i could add the users manually without having them to register any help will be appreciated thank you.

Comment: No server = no accounts. Accounts are not a property of web pages, they're part of online services, which require online SERVERS and therefore databases to store this information.

Comment: Where are you planning on storing your user information then? in a .txt file?

Comment: Are you doing this on a local computer, or do you have a web server "on the web"? Actually, I am wondering if your site is on a server that can do some PHP? If so, then yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only place that client side technologies can store data is in the browser. That means:

- Data won't be shared between users of different browsers
- Anyone with access to the browser can edit the data

You need to use a server side technology. There are [plenty of options which use JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_server-side_JavaScript_solutions), of which [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is currently popular, for the language, and [plenty of databases that aren't MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems) so you can achieve what you ask for (although probably not what you want).